# Colours/Background messed up in VNC Viewer

Tags: vnc, vncviewer

I've set up vncserver on my new build and I can connect using RealVNC VNC Viewer, however the colours are a bit off and it looks kind of awful. See this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

What can I do to put this right?

I've been using depth 24 when creating the vnc session, but as far as I can see no other depths make a difference. Is it something else?

Comment: can you share your `.vnc/xstartup` file settings for accessing gnome desktop through vnc?

Answer (score 5):

If you want full wicked colours follow this simple steps:

1. Open **VNC VIEWER**

   [image]
2. Select **OPTIONS**

   [image]
3. Unselect **Adapt to Network Speed**

   [image]
4. Drag the bar to the quality you wish to have

   [image]
5. To the Right is the best colour option but uses more bandwidth. To the left you have less bandwidth use but also less colours.

   [image]

Now connect to the place you want.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Hats off, sir!

Comment: Works with other vnc clients as well, f.ex. TigerVNC.

Answer (score 2):

*Answered by the OP in the question:*

> Never mind, I just changed the desktop background to a plain color and
>   it's okay now.

Comment: I don't mind people editing my posts, but when you edit them to remove correct spellings and put in incorrect ones that's taking the biscuit...

Comment: I don't understand whatever are you trying to say. Please, create a new answer telling how did you solved your issue if you want to. In such a case I will delete this. If you have something wrong with something on the answer, you can *edit* it..

Comment: @Conn Firstly: Anyone and everyone can edit everyone's posts. If that's not OK with you then this probably isn't the place for you. See the [FAQ]. Second: "*color*" is the American version of the British "*colour*", so it's still correct. Rather a trivial thing I know, but then, this *is* the internet. It's diverse. Thirdly: Being rude is *absolutely 100% NOT allowed*. After all, it's *just* a word.